# Connection refused error while sending push notification through GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am trying to send the push notification from server application using below code but getting "connection refused error".I am using server API key, also google cloud messaging for android is enabled. Please suggest.

```
try {  
    final String API_KEY ="server api key"; 
    String CLIENT_REG_ID ="APA91bEZD2MFH7TzMvry1UR2ezqTSAwCbqRgIZ8qXo_h559TYId29j3u2zPyHzxiZrA65tVhtPlY9O77LnLRbqJf585YmwYccBrGoQ5OjPAz4xT_JfIGJ1AEyjq9EUEhawc2V4kMrIar"; 
    final String postData = "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + CLIENT_REG_ID + "\" ], " +
             "\"delay_while_idle\": true, " +
             "\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"My Ticket\", " +
             "\"contentTitle\":\"My Title\", " +
             "\"message\": \"Test GCM message from GCMServer-Android\"}}";                      


     URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
     HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
     urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);

     OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
     writer.write(postData);
     writer.flush();
     writer.close();
     outputStream.close();

     int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
     System.out.println("response code is"+responseCode);
     InputStream inputStream;

     if (responseCode < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
         inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
     } else {
         inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
     }

     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
     String temp, response = "";

     while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         response += temp;
     }

} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();    
}
```

Comment: Please post your manifest. Have you added permissions in it?

Comment: @GauravJindal: i am calling this code from server application not from android client

Comment: Ohh I am sorry.  I thought you it was client contacting server.

Comment: What is the error on the server side? Is it 401 Unauthorized?

Comment: Check the validity of your API key as described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey)